# Access other Java classes

Tags: java, arrays, methods, netbeans

I am a Java beginner and two questions boggle me really hard,  so I have these questions.
For instance, I do not understand why in the Class Suitcase the method call `getWeight()` can be called, but in the Class Hold the method call `totalWeight()` not.

It works here:

```
 public int totalWeight() {
        int momentaryWeight = 0;
        for (Item items: this.itemList) {
            momentaryWeight = momentaryWeight + items.getWeight();
        }
        return momentaryWeight;
    }
```

But not here:

```
 public String toString() {
        int momentaryWeight = 0;
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = index; i < this.suitcaseList.size(); i++) {
            Suitcase suitcaseChosen = this.suitcaseList.get(i);
            int weightOfsuitcaseChosen = suitcaseChosen.totalWeight();
            momentaryWeight += weightOfsuitcaseChosen;
        }
```

Also when having a method that returns something and using an if statement (so 2 return statements) it asks me afterwards for another return statement, like here:

```
public Item printGoods() {
    if (this.itemList.isEmpty() == true) {
        return null;
    } else {
    for (Item itemThis: this.itemList) {
        return itemThis;
    }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I know that maybe these are dull questions, but I couldn't think of a better forum to understand it.
Thanks.

The Hold class:

```
public class Hold {
    private int maxWeight;
    private ArrayList<Suitcase> suitcaseList;

    public Hold(int maxWeightGiven) {
        this.maxWeight = maxWeightGiven;
        this.suitcaseList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addSuitcase(Suitcase suitcase) {
       this.suitcaseList.add(suitcase); 
    }

    public String toString() {
        int momentaryWeight = 0;
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = index; i < this.suitcaseList.size(); i++) {
            Suitcase suitcaseChosen = this.suitcaseList.get(i);
            int weightOfsuitcaseChosen = suitcaseChosen.totalWeight();
            momentaryWeight += weightOfsuitcaseChosen;
        }
        return this.suitcaseList.size() + " suitcases" + " (" + momentaryWeight + " kg)";
    }
```

The Suitcase class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Suitcase {
    private int maximumWeight;
    private ArrayList<Item> itemList;

public Suitcase(int maximumWeightGiven) {
    this.maximumWeight = maximumWeightGiven;
    this.itemList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addItem(Item item) {
    int momentaryWeight = 0;
    if (momentaryWeight <= this.maximumWeight && momentaryWeight + item.getWeight() <= this.maximumWeight) {
    this.itemList.add(item);    
    }
}


public int totalWeight() {
    int momentaryWeight = 0;
    for (Item items: this.itemList) {
        momentaryWeight = momentaryWeight + items.getWeight();
    }
    return momentaryWeight;
}
```

The class Item looks like this:

```
    public class Item {
        private String name;
        private int weight;

        public Item(String nameGiven, int weightGiven) {
            this.name = nameGiven;
            this.weight = weightGiven;
        }

         public String getName() {
             return this.name;
         }

         public int getWeight() {
             return this.weight;
         }

         public String toString() {
             return this.name + "( " + this.weight + " kg)";
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: What classes are the `toString` and `totalWeight` in?

Comment: I believe I would be able to answer you if you posted a [mcve].

Comment: Programming is hard, start with the tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: Regarding your second question: if you declare a return type, *all possible code paths must eventually return something  of that type. What if `itemList` contains zero items (so `return itemThis` will never be executed), and `isEmpty()` returns `false`? (Which would be wrong, but it *could* be...)

Comment: I am sorry, I couldn't post the whole code, because it was too long. I will post a screen image.

Comment: Other notes: Never use `==` with a boolean; it's already true or false. Strongly prefer returning an empty list to returning null; it makes life easier for everyone. Use the for-each loop instead of `get(i)` in almost all circumstances. Here, you can make it even clearer with a stream if you're allowed to use them: `itemList.stream().mapToInt(Item::getWeight).sum()`.

Comment: I am sorry, I have already edited my post and it includes now only code, no images. I promise in the future postings, I will (hopefully) abide the rules as they should be. Thanks MC Emperor for clearing this problem. Also thanks chrylis -on strike, but it may take a while until I am there at streams.

Answer (score 0):

First question is incomplete code and detail.

Second question: suppose `if-condition` is false and your loop condition is also false(empty array) then the program will not reach to return statement that's why you have to add an extra return statement.

You can move last `return` line inside the `else block`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The one with the if-condition is now clear to me. I have added the code for everyone to follow (the code itself comes from an online course).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what happened, but as I worked on it a while later, suddenly the error messages disappeared and I was able to run the program. Is there a special key in NetBeans for "Refreshing"?